# Sending SMS from android phone to all normal headsets like nokia 1100

Tags: android

Is there any way to send SMS to another device using internet? I don't want to use the phone native network. I wish to use the internet to send messages like way2sms.com.

I'm not talking about android applications like Viber, WhatsApp Messenger, etc. If we are using those services, other devices we need to send SMS must have installed the same application. But I don't want to do that. If at all, I want to install an app only on my Android device and send SMS to other devices using internet. (other devices means all other devices which can receive SMS - not only smart phones but also devices like Nokia 1100). I used:

```
public void sendMessage() {

    String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
    String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I send sms through only network. Kindly help me.

Comment: so, you want to send sms from internet and the receivers to get it on the network? or did I get it wrong?

Comment: cent percent correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send SMS using Internet, you will need a SMS gateway. There are many SMS gateway providers like Way2SMS, you can find out one in your region. To communicate with SMS gateway, you will have to use the APIs provided by them. Its usually a simple HTTP call.

Check the links below for reference-

https://github.com/kingster/Way2SMS-API

http://firewithjava.blogspot.in/2012/04/way2sms-java-api-2012.html